# a question on Costello's theorem

Tags: mirror-symmetry, gromov-witten-theory

Costello's theorem,"open TCFT=Calabi Yau A-infinity category",he also mentions when applied to Fukaya category we can recover Gromov-Witten theory, but I see that it needs some assumption,also even if the assumption is true,I just see that the TCFT associated to Fukaya category is the same as the one associated to Gromov-Witten invariant, BUT can we from that TCFT to RECOVER Gromov-Witten invariants? (I mean the opposite direction) Because otherwise,it is not A model.

I appreciate if there is any answer.

Comment: This is an open question. See http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509264 and http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.0107

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is “no”.

Comment: If Costello's theorem is what you're interested in, section 4.2 of the Lurie(-Hopkins) article on the classification on TCFT's describes a generalization that may be better suited to deal with this.

Comment: Kevin, do you read that paper"The Gromov-Witten potential associated to a TCFT", I have several questions?